# C language crack password

Tags: c, cs50

Question:
1. the code is used to encypt the no more than 5 digits passwords. I can test 1,2,3,4 digit when only left 1,2,3,4 for..language.
but it does not work well with 5 digit password.
2. also i want to use the code to test no more than 5 digit passwords at once but I do not know how to achieve that?

```
else
{
    string hash = argv[1];
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrestuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   // salt is the first two letter of hash
   // same key and same salt will come to the same hash
    char salt[2];
    salt[0] = hash[0];
    salt[1] = hash[1];
    char key[5];

    int i,m,n,p,s;


    for (i=0; i<strlen(alphabet); i++)
     {
        for (m=0; m<strlen(alphabet); m++)
        {
            for (n=0; n<strlen(alphabet);n++)
            {
                for (p=0; p<strlen(alphabet); p++)
                {
                    for( s=0; s<strlen(alphabet);s++)
                    {
                     key[0]=alphabet[i];
                     key[1]=alphabet[m];
                     key[2]=alphabet[n];
                     key[3]=alphabet[p];
                     key[4]=alphabet[s];

                     if (strcmp(crypt(key,salt),hash) == 0)
                     {
                       printf("%s\n",key);
                       return 0;
                     }
                    }
                  }

              }

        }

    }
 }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `crypt(key,salt)` certainly expects 2 _strings_ - or at least form one for `strcmp()`.  `key[]` is not a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_.